Error related to Automated checks and frame suppression are incompatible FrameBustingUtils
This is the problem, in the Oracle ADF development environment, I did a start IntegratedWebLogicServer. I went to the WebLogic console, to the test page of my application and a white screen appears. On the console in the Oracle ADF development environment, this error appears:
<org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.util.FrameBustingUtils> <FrameBustingUtils> <disableFrameBustingForTesting> <Automation of checks is enabled. Automation of checks and frame suppression are incompatible, therefore, if support for automation of checks is enabled, then its operating mode will be similar to the mode in which the context parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.security.FRAME_BUSTING' is set to 'never'>
Version of oracle adf = Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.0.0
What should I do? Thanks a lot.

Please read the docs at Oracle Adf Configuration Files section 'A.2.3.18 Framebusting'
